# Swift UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout

Tags: swift

I am using UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout to size the cells in a horizontally scrolling collectionView.

When the ViewController loads the cells in the collectionview are the expected size. However when I scroll the subsequent cells which are shown don't have the correct size applied.

Why is this occuring and how do I ensure all the cells are the correct size?

Correct size on load:

[image: on load]

Sizing after scroll:

[image: after scroll]

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import Firebase

class Bundles: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    var bundleArray: [bundleStruct] = []

    @IBOutlet var collectionView: UICollectionView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        self.collectionView.register(UINib(nibName: "BundleCell", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "BundleCell")
        collectionView.dataSource = self
        collectionView.delegate = self
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        DatabaseClass.getBundles(completion: { result in
            self.bundleArray = result
            self.collectionView.reloadData()
        })
    }

  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.size.width / 2, height: collectionView.frame.size.height)
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return bundleArray.count * 3
       }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell : BundleCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "BundleCell", for: indexPath) as! BundleCell
           return cell
       }

}
```

Comment: this isn't a complete scroll , the part hides the remaining content of the 3rd cell ?

Comment: Hi, if you look at the text which says "0 credits = 0 messages" as a point of reference you can see how the cells increase in size during the scroll

Comment: video: we.tl/t-7Kdv8Z4nDt